# how to give parameter to sub report in rdlc report asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have one main SSRS report which uses two sub-reports. The main report has two parameters that I need to pass to the sub-reports.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2005.

```
 RViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;        
        RViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MOM.rdlc");
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("meetingmaster", getdt);
        RViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        RViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new ReportParameter[1];       //Array size describes the number of paramaters.
        reportParameterCollection[0] = new ReportParameter();
        reportParameterCollection[0].Name = "mrefno";                                 //Give Your Parameter Name
        reportParameterCollection[0].Values.Add(mref);                         //Pass Parametrs's value here.
        RViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
        RViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Shouldn't your main report pass all parameters to sub-reports?

Comment: Only if the sub-reports need all of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The main report will need to be written to pass the parameters to the sub-reports. This is done with the properties on the sub report object in the designer. I'm not sure that you can pass parameters to a sub-report directly using only code which calls the reports.

One issue you may have is that SSRS 2005 reports need Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) version 2005. If you try to modify the report definitions with Visual Studio 2010 you may not be able to deploy the reports to the server. (BIDS is just Visual Studio with extra templates and functionality for BI development.)